# How does this x86 Assembly code create a string?

Tags: string, assembly, x86, disassembly

I'm studying the x86 assembly language. In order to better understand what's going on behind the scenes of string creation, I have a sample program that just prints a string. GCC produced the following Assembly program, and I'm having trouble understanding the compiler's output:

**Assembly Code:**

```
Dump of assembler code for function main:
   0x0000000000400596 <+0>: push   %rbp
   0x0000000000400597 <+1>: mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x000000000040059a <+4>: sub    $0x10,%rsp
   0x000000000040059e <+8>: movq   $0x400668,-0x8(%rbp)
   0x00000000004005a6 <+16>:    mov    -0x8(%rbp),%rax
   0x00000000004005aa <+20>:    mov    %rax,%rsi
=> 0x00000000004005ad <+23>:    mov    $0x400675,%edi
   0x00000000004005b2 <+28>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x00000000004005b7 <+33>:    callq  0x4004a0 <printf@plt>
   0x00000000004005bc <+38>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x00000000004005c1 <+43>:    leaveq 
   0x00000000004005c2 <+44>:    retq
```

**C Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
char *me = "abcdefghijkl";
printf("%s",me);
}
```

At the conceptual level, I understand that the stack pointer is being subtracted to allocate memory on the stack, and then somehow, **and this is the part I'm having trouble understanding the mechanics of**, the program creates the string.

Can someone please help?
Thanks.

Comment: Could you post your C code here as well?

Comment: There's no pointer arithmetic here. The address of the string stored into `me` is 0x400668. The address of the variable `me` is `-8(rbp)`. The address of the format string `"%s"` is 0x4004a0.

Comment: @prl Interesting. So let me ask you this: Suppose I wanted to go into the assembly code and change the string to "123456". What would I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a lot clearer if you use the `-S` flag to `gcc` to create an assembly file for your program (`gcc -S asm.c`). This generates a `asm.s` file:

```
        .file   "asm.c"
        .section        .rodata
.LC0:
        .string "abcdefghijkl"
.LC1:
        .string "%s"
        .text
        .globl  main
        .type   main, @function
main:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        subq    $16, %rsp
        movq    $.LC0, -8(%rbp)
        movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
        movq    %rax, %rsi
        movl    $.LC1, %edi
        movl    $0, %eax
        call    printf
        leave
        .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
        .size   main, .-main
        .ident  "GCC: (GNU) 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)"
        .section        .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

From this you can see that the string is just some initialized memory in the `.rodata` section assigned the label `.LC0`. Changing that memory changes the string.